# Error when fiting linear binary classifier with tensorflow ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have an error when trying to fit a linear binary classifier using step function and MSE, instead of softmax and cross-entropy loss. I have and error which I can't overcome probably due to shape inconsistencies. I provide a code sample. Please help

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification as gen_data
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
rng = np.random

# Setting hyperparameters
n_observations = 100
lr = 0.005
n_iter = 100

# Generate input data 
xs, ys = gen_data(n_features=2, n_redundant=0, n_informative=2, 
                  random_state=0, n_clusters_per_class=1)
# Split data into train and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(xs, ys, test_size=.4)
X_train = np.float32(X_train)
X_test = np.float32(X_test)

# Graph
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

W = tf.Variable(np.float32(rng.randn(2)), name="weight")
b = tf.Variable(np.float32(rng.randn()), name="bias")

def step(x):
    is_greater = tf.greater(x, 0)
    as_float = tf.to_float(is_greater)
    doubled = tf.multiply(as_float, 2)

    return tf.subtract(doubled, 1)

Y_pred = step(tf.add(tf.multiply(X , W), b))

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(Y_pred, Y))
# Using built-in optimization algorithm to train the model:
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.005).minimize(cost)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

for step in range(n_iter):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={X:X_train, Y:y_train})
    print ("iter: {0}; weight: {1}; bias: {2}".format(step, 
                                                      sess.run(W), 
                                                      sess.run(b)))
```

This is the error:

```
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-5a0c4711802c> in <module>()
     26 
     27 # Using built-in optimization algorithm to train the model:
---> 28 train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.005).minimize(cost)
     29 
     30 # Using TF differentiation from scratch to implement a step-by-step optimizer

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.pyc in minimize(self, loss, global_step, var_list, gate_gradients, aggregation_method, colocate_gradients_with_ops, name, grad_loss)
    405           "No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops"
    406           " that do not support gradients, between variables %s and loss %s." %
--> 407           ([str(v) for _, v in grads_and_vars], loss))
    408 
    409     return self.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, global_step=global_step,

ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables ["<tf.Variable 'weight:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float64_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'bias:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'weight_1:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float64_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'bias_1:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>",
```

Answer (score -1):

Your training data isn't changing between training steps. That is, each training step feeds the same values for `X` and `Y`:

```
for step in range(n_iter):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={X:X_train, Y:y_train})
```

If you set different values for `X` and `Y` between training steps, the error should go away.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewScarpino. I suppose you mean giving batches iteratively, but it isn't possible to train the model with a unique batch? I think that's I'm doing, it isn't correct?

Comment: The training process requires multiple batches containing different data. If you feed the same data over and over again, the optimizer won't be able to work properly.